# How to swap object with taquito

Tags: taquito

I'm trying to swap NFT using such function:

```
async function swap(fa2: string, contractAddress: string, objkt_id: number, royalties: number, objkt_amount: number, xtz_per_objkt: number, owner_address: string, creator: string, privateKey: string) {

    try {
        tezos.setProvider({signer: await InMemorySigner.fromSecretKey(privateKey)});

        // Load the marketplace contract
        const marketplaceContract = await tezos.contract.at(contractAddress);


        // Call the swap entry point with the provided parameters
        const operation = await marketplaceContract.methods.swap(creator, objkt_amount, objkt_id, royalties, xtz_per_objkt).send();

        // Await confirmation
        const confirmation = await operation.confirmation();

        if (confirmation.completed) {
            console.log(`Successfully swapped NFT with token ID ${objkt_id}.`);
        } else {
            console.log('Failed to swap NFT.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error swap NFT:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

But it produces error `TezosOperationError: FA2_NOT_OPERATOR`

Comment: Which account is calling the function? By default only the token owner is the OPERATOR with permissions to transfer it.

Comment: @ktorn I think I'm a bit confused with terminology here. The function is called by account, who owns a token but is not a token creator. So my goal is to resell token using this API

Comment: Perhaps you need to temporarily add the contract as a valid operator. See https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/best-practices-for-checking-adding-removing-operators-for-a-users-fa2-tokens-wi

Comment: As I understand, `update_operators` should be one of the contract methods. But when I'm getting contract by `await tezos.contract.at("KT1HbQepzV1nVGg8QVznG7z4RcHseD5kwqBn")` it only has these methods:  update_manager,  update_fee, swap, collect, cancel_swap

Comment: That's the HEN v2 contract, you may want to refer to the original HEN UI code for reference: https://github.com/hicetnunc2000/hicetnunc/blob/ebfbb55144a83b247b327388066f37a1e27328f8/src/context/HicetnuncContext.js#L185

it seems like the update_operators method is on the objkts contract, rather than the marketplace contract.

Comment: Nice! That worked like a charm, thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code example from https://github.com/hicetnunc2000/hicetnunc/blob/ebfbb55144a83b247b327388066f37a1e27328f8/src/context/HicetnuncContext.js#L185 worked in my case

My implementation:

```
async function swapv2(fa2Address, contractAddress, royalties, objkt_amount, xtz_per_objkt, objkt_id, creator, ownerAddress) {
    // If using proxy: both calls are made through this.state.proxyAddress:
    // const objktsAddress = this.state.proxyAddress || this.state.objkts;
    // const marketplaceAddress = this.state.proxyAddress || this.state.v2;
    // const ownerAddress = this.state.proxyAddress || from;

    let fa2 = await tezos.wallet.at(fa2Address)
    let marketplace = await tezos.wallet.at(contractAddress)

    let list = [
        {
            kind: OpKind.TRANSACTION,
            ...fa2.methods.update_operators([{
                add_operator: {
                    operator: contractAddress,
                    token_id: parseFloat(objkt_id),
                    owner: ownerAddress
                }
            }])
                .toTransferParams({amount: 0, mutez: true, storageLimit: 175})
        },
        {
            kind: OpKind.TRANSACTION,
            ...marketplace.methods.swap(creator, parseFloat(objkt_amount), parseFloat(objkt_id), parseFloat(royalties), parseFloat(xtz_per_objkt)).toTransferParams({
                amount: 0,
                mutez: false,
                storageLimit: 300
            })
        },
        {
            kind: OpKind.TRANSACTION,
            ...fa2.methods.update_operators([{
                remove_operator: {
                    operator: contractAddress,
                    token_id: parseFloat(objkt_id),
                    owner: ownerAddress
                }
            }])
                .toTransferParams({amount: 0, mutez: true, storageLimit: 175})
        },
    ]

    let batch = await tezos.wallet.batch(list);
    return await batch.send()
}
```

Comment: great!
can you please edit your answer to include a code excerpt from the source (in case the link stops working) and accept your own answer.

Comment: Added code, it doesn't allow accepting my own answer yet

Comment: no worries. thanks for editing the question. the code will be useful for others in the future.